# angularjs bind template as item inside ngrepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a special situation in the angularjs, i cant template inside ngRepeat that template is a parameter of item

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="item in items" >
<td data-ng-repeat="column in columns" ng-bind-html="resolve(item,column)"></td>
</tr>
```

controller code :

```
$scope.columns:[{ name: "id" },
            { name: "name" },
            { name: "lastName"},
            { name: "name", template: "<a href='#/xx/{{item.id}}' >edit</a>"},
            { name: "name", template: "<button ng-click='del()' href='#'>del</button>" }]
```

and resolve function is:

```
  $scope.resolve = function(item,col){
         if (col.template) {
            // i dont know for this
         } else {
          return sce.trustAsHtml("<span>" + item[col.name] + "</span>");
           }
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Look [here](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/). though it would probably be easier to use `ng-switch`.

Comment: do you have any error on console?

Comment: no, but i try to compile column template, it occure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already done a sample like as your sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9BMP8/). In this sample, I created more a custom directive named "dynamic" to resolve and compile the HTML string automatically in AngularJS.

HTML

```
<table ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="templateController">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
            <td ng-bind="item.name"><td>                               
            <td dynamic="item.template"></td>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.directive('dynamic', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, ele, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.dynamic, function(html) {
        ele.html(html);
        $compile(ele.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
  };
});
myApp.controller('templateController', function ($scope){
    $scope.items = [{ name: "id" },
            { name: "name" },
            { name: "lastName"},
                    { id: 1, name: "name", template: "<a href='#/xx/{{item.id}}' >edit</a>"},
            { name: "name", template: "<button ng-click='del()' href='#'>del</button>" }];
});
```

Hope this will help you!!

Comment: YES,I combined it with my code and result is here http://plnkr.co/edit/VWwRb52TxKcgldaBZaw7

Answer (score 0):

I am making a few speculations on your logic, but this smells to me like the job of a directive.

Check out the plunker i made to show my point:

http://plnkr.co/edit/zW6LYKNQxgfRszwY0eV2?p=preview

Also looking at the example code you have given:

```
$scope.columns:[{ name: "id" },
            { name: "name" },
            { name: "lastName"},
            { name: "name", template: "<a href='#/xx/{{item.id}}' >edit</a>"},
            { name: "name", template: "<button ng-click='del()' href='#'>del</button>" }]
```

$scope.columns = not :

Comment: my code is inside a directive as grid,i need to set template for some columns

Comment: If you can provide a better example of the code then I can provide a better example of a solution - also i updated the plnkr as i saw it was missing a couple fields...

Comment: In my opinion your data object - gridOptions is too complex and needs to be broken up into multiple objects each with their own function. I cant imaging a server returning such a convoluted object. Which is why in my original example I broke the html into a directive.